# Unable to connect to Restfull API on local machine through an emulator using Xamarin.IOS

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building my first Xamarin application and attempted to use it to connect to a Restful API on the same machine. The reason we have chosen Xamarin is so we can build one application to run on multiple devices.

Se we have an external WebAPI project that runs on IISExpress we have set the URL to http://127.0.0.1:5001

In our Xamarin project we can successfully connect to the API project using both the UWP & Android application through corresponding emulators within Visual Studio. Here is an example of what I am using to differentiate between the device emulator being run.

```
    public static string BaseAddress = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? "http://10.0.2.2:5001"
        : Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "http://localhost:5001"
        : "http://127.0.0.1:5001";
    public static string TodoItemsUrl = BaseAddress + "/api/Appointment/GetAppointments";
```

It's when trying to call our API controller when we run an iOS emulator. It seems that no request is made whatsoever. I have tried lots and lots of different things and just cannot seem to get a solution. Also finding the documentation out there very vague. Has anyone got any idea why this might be happening?

I am regularly receiving

```
       System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does TCP Socket Implementation Work Differently in Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592889/does-tcp-socket-implementation-work-differently-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate  of [this existing question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592889/does-tcp-socket-implementation-work-differently-in-xamarin-android)  which is itself probably a duplicate of uncountable other questions with identical solutions.

Comment: It makes no difference.  The problem and the solution are the same.

Comment: do NOT use localhost - use the actual IP address of the server.  You will also need to setup IIS Express to allow remote connections.  Both of these topics are covered hundreds of times in other questions on SO and elsewhere on the web

Comment: The problem is simply that the PC is **not** "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 as seen from the phone (whether iOS or Android.)

Comment: I've put it to 192.168.1.XX lots of times to no avail. It's just when I posted the question that was it's current state. So I need to set it to its actual ip address and switch on allow remote connections to IIS Express. Just looking for the right property in applicatiohost.config.

Comment: The problem is on two sides.  The IIS Express must have an IP address that can be reached from the emulator, and the emulator must be configured to allow network access to the PC from the emulated phone.

Comment: So I would be better off using local IIS rather than IIS Express by the sound of it because I can't get it to work.

Comment: I managed to resolve it, thanks for your help. I just stopped using IISExpress completely and did it through LocalIIS. So I have learnt from this the best thing to do here is don't use IISExpress at all because of the loopback issue.

Comment: You can write the solution as an answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resolution to this problem IMO is to forgo IISExpress completely when working in Visual Studio IDE and revert to using LocalIIS. That way we can specify the API address as an IP; like in the range of 192.168.. This ensures we can still debug things and successfully avoid the loopback problems that will arise by mounting the emulators.