# Xamarin.Forms connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I connect Xamarin.Forms cross-platform to SQL Server?

This just hangs and does not connect to SQL Server and does not show any sign of connection. I have added `System.Data.SqlClient` as a reference.

My code looks something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SqlConExample
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void connectBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=people_Database;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring)) 
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    await DisplayAlert("OK", "OK i am Connected", "OK");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you directly connect your mobile application as a client to a SQL database server, always adding a Web-API based middle layer is recommended.

Comment: asmx webservice? I cannot see where i can add to use a service reference

Comment: What I am saying here is why would you want a mobile application to have the details to directly connect to your database? Where there is a fair chance that you Android APK can be reverse engineered to get this! Also, it's just too much for a mobile app to handle don't you think? Why not just let you API's do the heavy lifting?

Comment: I have tried doing with PHP Mysql for several days now and have quarreled with so many of us here and i have been very unable to get it to work. Should u accept , i can share my project (Demo) so you can see and put me in the right direction. Pls @FreakyAli

Comment: Are you running this in an Android (or an Android emulator) or are you trying to run it local on your PC first?

Comment: @JRE i am running it from an Emulator

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are running the program in an emulator.

The SQL server is on your PC.  The emulator has its own IP address which is different from the IP address of the PC.

Your code says "connect me to the SQL server on the local address."

That's this line:

```
string constring = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=people_Database;Integrated Security=True";
```

".\SQLExpress" refers to the local machine.  When you run that code in the emulator, the local machine is the emulated Android.

[This question has the same cause, and the same solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592889/does-tcp-socket-implementation-work-differently-in-xamarin-android/)

You must address the SQL server on your PC using its IP address as seen by the emulator.

Possible IP addresses:

1. Google simulators: 10.0.2.2 is the address of your PC as seen from the Android.
2. Microsoft simulators: 169.254.80.80 is the address of your PC as seen from the Android.

Assuming you are using a Microsoft emulator, you would need to change your connection string to:

```
string constring = @"Data Source=169.254.80.80\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=people_Database;Integrated Security=True";
```

You will also have to make sure that your SQL server is listening on all addresses.

---

As others have said in the comments, it is a **bad** idea to connect from your phone to an SQL server.  That would mean that your SQL server has to be available on all the networks your phone could connect on.  Basically:  You would have to expose your SQL server to the entire internet.  That's generally regarded as a bad thing to do.

Comment: What is the difference between having your REST API exposed to the whole Internet and your SQL Server with the DB exposed to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Use Web API's Instead. Connecting SQL directly is not recommended.