# TCP Socket not receiving connections

Tags: c#, android, sockets, maui

I am working a local proxy app. I have already implemented the proxy code in C# and it is working fine and bug free on Windows, Linux, and Mac OSx. However when I try to run the system on Android, I face this issue:

1. The socket starts without any problem
2. The socket starts listening to 127.0.0.1 8080
3. I set a global proxy by going to Wi-Fi and connection setting and I point it to 127.0.0.1  8080
4. But when I start browsing something, the TCP socket receives no connection

The TCP socket has been implemented using the following approach:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080));
socket.Listen(1000);
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Socket accept = socket.Accept();
        // I don't reach here 
    }
}
```

I start it in another thread so that the app would not get irresponsive.

In the beginning I thought it's a permission problem so I set the following permissions as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true"  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

But the socket starts without any issue as I use break points to see what is going on, and the global proxy setting is correct. Now I expect to receive connections but nothing is received by the socket. In other platforms it works as expected.

Comment: `The socket starts listening to 127.0.0.1 8080` Why to 127.0.0.1 and 8080? Just open a listening port for 8080. Why bind to an ip address. If you do only incoming comnections from 127.0.0.1 (from the same device) will be accepted.

Comment: Is this Android Device or Android Emulator?

Comment: @H.A.H.: Yes it is

Comment: Here is a similar case about: [Does TCP Socket Implementation Work Differently in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592889/does-tcp-socket-implementation-work-differently-in-xamarin-android), it is suggested you could refer to it.